# oracle query to extract all the dates within given periods and range

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider if there is a table with two column

```
TABLE TIME_FRAME
------------------------
|FROM       |TO        |
|2013-12-13 |2014-01-06|
|2011-12-05 |2011-12-31|
|2014-01-23 |2014-02-22|
|2011-11-21 |2011-12-17|
........
```

`FROM` and `TO` from each row defines a period of time. Also there can be overlap between the periods (here row 2 and row 4) or cover multiple periods

if give a `start_date` and `end_date` as parameters here the requirement is about return all the dates falls within the parameters and also within any of the periods in the columns

for example 
if `start_date` is `2013-12-25` and `end_date` is `2014-02-10`
so from above data it should return all dates between

```
`2013-12-25` and `2014-01-06`
plus
`2014-01-23` and `2014-02-10`
```

is it possible to create a query for above requirement (not by PL/SQL)?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366270/overlap-function-in-oracle or https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/overlapping-date-ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by creating set of days using LEVEL recursion operator and then filtering this set by comparing it to your table data. Here is the working Oracle SQL query for you:

```
select day
  from (select to_date('25-DEC-2013', 'dd-mon-yyyy') - 1 + level day
          from dual
        connect by level <= to_date('10-FEB-2014', 'dd-mon-yyyy') -
                   to_date('25-DEC-2013', 'dd-mon-yyyy') + 1)
 where exists
 (select 1 from TIME_FRAME p where day between p.FROM and p.TO);
```

Hope this helps!